# Convert only some columns from DB Entity object to a comma delimited list

Tags: c#, arrays, entity-framework, linq

I have a table (let's call it `Reg`) that looks like this:

```
RegId    FirstName    LastName    City         CreatedBy    DateCreated
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1       John          Doe        New York       123          1/1/2017
  2       Jane          Doe        Miami          298          2/2/2017
```

I need to get only some of the columns from this table into a comma delimited flat file.  I'm not sure of the most efficient way to select only some of the columns, get them into a `List<String>` or array of `String[]`, so that it can then be written to the flat file.

I need every row, so I can start here:

```
var regs = Context.Reg.ToList();
```

`regs` now has every column in every row.  But, let's say I only need:

```
FirtName, LastName, City
```

How do I best extract just those columns and get them into a `List<String>` or array of `String[]`.  In reality, there will be MUCH more than just three columns.  I'm just trying to keep it simple for the sake of this question. I add this because I would *rather not* create a separate object into which I select just the columns I want.

**EDIT:**

Just so I'm making sense, what I want to get to is this:

```
John,Doe,New York
Jane,Doe,Miami
```

Comment: How do you determine what Properties (*ie. db columns*) you need? Is it hard coded? Something you get from the user at run time? Configurable from a file or something?

Comment: Now when we know what ORM are you using, forget about LINQ and ORM, build raw SQL, open a reader, read record by record and write to file :)

Comment: Good question.  It's pre-determined and won't change. So, hard coded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Added ToList() after Context.Reg, since EntityFramework does not support String.Join, so we have to pull the data into memory first, because we can select.

Query syntax:

```
var list = (from col in Context.Reg.ToList()
            select String.Join(",", x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.City/*additonal columns here*/))
            .ToList();
```

Fluent syntax:

```
var list = Context.Reg.ToList()
               .Select(x => String.Join(",", x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.City/*additonal columns here*/))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Ah!  This looks perfect!  I'll test this and brb.

Comment: This will not work in entity framework as it doesn't understand what string.Join is

Comment: Good luck with EF! *Method "string.Join" is not supported in LINQ to Entities context*.

Comment: yeah - they are right.  {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: Today is not my day.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

These things can be very important if you are working with a larger table, if you just retrieve everything it could result in an `OutOfMemoryException`

- Use `AsNoTracking()`, this will ensure the instance does not stay attached to the `DbContext`

  - If using anonymous projection (*ie. a Select expression*) the `AsNoTracking()` can be ignored as it serves no purpose as the projection is not tracked by the context.
- Iterate using a loop directly from the `DbSet` (*or IQueryable is also ok if you want to add filtering later*), this will ensure that managed memory can be released while you are writing the records out to the stream.
- Write the produced string to a Stream inside the loop, do not aggregate the strings in memory.

For the line level string concatenation use `string.Join` and pass in the properties you want to include.

#### Code

```
using(var Context = new YourDbContext())
{
    // the Select expression is optional, if you have many properties on the model that are not used it can 
    // increase efficiency to only pull back what you are going to write to the stream
    // If using the Select you can safely omit AsNoTracking
    foreach(var record in Context.Reg.AsNoTracking().Select(x => new {x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.City /* etc */ }))
    {
        var stringToWrite = string.Join(",", record.FirstName, record.LastName, record.City /* etc. */);
        // write the string to a stream or output
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course a drawback is that this first retrieves full `Reg` records, albeit not tracked.

Comment: @GertArnold - possible drawback I guess, it depends also on how much of the `Reg` record is unused (pulled back for no reason).

Comment: True. And all this also applies the other (now accepted) answer.

Comment: @GertArnold - I added an optional `Select` which could remove that possible overhead.

Comment: With "optional select" (a.k.a. anonymous projection), there is no more need of `AsNotracking`

Comment: @IvanStoev - Yeah, I should have put something in there when I made my last edit. Updated and thank you.

Comment: Personally, I think your answer should be the selected one, not mine.

Comment: You are welcome. Now this would have been my chosen answer. But OP of course accepted the most inefficient :)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the columns you need upfront, you can use this pattern:

```
context.Regs
       .Select(r => new List<string> { r.FirstName, r.LastName, r.City })
       .AsEnumerable().Select(list => string.Join(",", list))
```

This doesn't require an intermediate class and (because of the `AsEnumerable()`) it doesn't use `string.Join` directly in a LINQ-to-Entities query, which isn't supported.

Although this is a convenient and quite succinct way to write the query, the generated SQL isn't too elegant. You'll have to test if it will perform sufficiently.

You can also use `r.DateCreated.ToString()` etc. `ToString` for most primitive types is supported since Entity Framework 6.1.1 (or thereabout). Of course, it depends on the database culture and settings which strings will be returned.

Comment: once the columns are known upfront, isn't it better to project to anonymous type in L2E, then do the `string.Join` after `AsEnumerable()`, making the necessary string formatting as well?

Comment: I tried to offer a solution without duplication of column names, just for the fun of it.